# How to change multiple lines using web forms in python?

Tags: python, flask

I have a text file that contains something like this :

```
host host_name {
# comment (optional)
    hardware ethernet 01:22:85:EA:A8:5D;
    fixed-address 192.168.107.210;
}

host another_host_name {
# comment (optional)
    hardware ethernet 01:22:85:EA:A8:5D;
    fixed-address 192.168.107.210;

}
```

I want my program to detect the line with the 'host' and then modify the content of the block according to what I type.

When I do the following (for example with `request.form.get('name')` in flask):

```
#random inputs
host = name2
comment = nothing
hardware = 00:00:00:00:00:00
address = 192.168.101.123
```

I would like to have :

```
host host_name {
# comment (optional)
    hardware ethernet 01:22:85:EA:A8:5D;
    fixed-address 192.168.107.210;
}

#after the change
host name2 {
# nothing
    hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
    fixed-address 192.168.101.123;

}
```

I don't have a problem with regex but rather the program that I have to do in order to achieve this, so how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you start to cod e the way you are thinking about your problem, you will likely have a complete and utter mess no ne can change or maintain, even if it works at first.

You have several different small tasks, and you are thinking of them "as one thing".

No. You are using Falsk to provide you an easy and light-weight web interface. That is ok. You already know how to get a text block from it. You don't need to ask anything about Flask now. Nor tio put any further code in the same place the code that gets data from the web is.

Instead just write some plain Python functions that will get your textual data as parameters, and then update the configuration files for you.

And while at that, if you can pick an special template and create a new config file when doing this, instead of trying to *parse* an existing file, and update your desired values in place, then, this is something you can achieve.

Parsing a "real world" config file in place and live update it is not an easy task. Actually it can be so complicated that most Linux distributions skipped trying that for more than 10 years.

And then you have a further complication you don't mention: you probably want to keep any configurations you are not changing on the file. I was to advise you to keep a template of the file, and fill in your data, creating a new file on each run.  But that would require you to have all the other config data in some other format, which would basically duplicate your problem.

So, ok, your idea of "getting data from the original file" with regular expressions might be a go. But still, keep it *separate* from writing back the file. And don't think in "lines" if said file is structured in blocks.

One feasible thing would be to read the file, get the data you are interested in into a Python data-structure (for example, a list of dictionaries, each one having your host_name, comment, ethernet and ip fields). And, in a second apply of the same regex, change all those for placeholders , so that the file contents could be filled back in by  a call to the `.format` method, or using Flask's jinja2 templating.

Separating the above in 2 functions will even allow you to present *all* the configured hosts on your web interface, so the user can edit then individually without having to type ethernet addresses by hand.

Sorry, but i won be writing all this code for you.   I hope the above can help you think about a proper approach there. So, if later you come up with other questions, with some code from your attempts, we can help you further.

Comment: I am beginner so I just thought of a way that uses what I already know. Basically I read the file, transform it into a dictionary list and display it in a table. What I would like to do is when a user clicks on a table row he is redirected to another page that has web forms that will be pre-filled with the data that he clicked on but all of this is complicated to do and to ask here. I will try to find a way on how to do it and maybe make another topic to ask about one of the details that concern my program. Thanks for your time and explanation.